# Least Squares Regression Matrix for Rational Functions

Tags: polynomials, regression

So first off no, this isn't a homework problem.
Second, I'm trying to understand how this works, NOT find a program that will do it for me.

Okay so I've known for a while how to use Gaussian-Jordan Elimination to interpolate a polynomial.  Recently I came across [this](http://www.arachnoid.com/sage/polynomial.html) article, which explains how to use multiple linear regression to fit a polynomial

Similarly I also learned how to interpolate for Rational Polynomials.  So now I'm trying to figure out how to fit a rational function to a set of data.  Specifically, I'm trying to understand how to setup the Matrix so that I can use Gaussian-Jordan elimination to find the coefficients.

Because I know interpolation and regression are similar (and in case it wasn't clear from my question), when I refer to interpolation, I mean only having just enough points to solve for the variables.  When I say regression, I mean you have more that enough points, and you're trying to find a function that adequately fits all of them

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use linear regression to 
try to minimize $\sum_j \left(\dfrac{p(x_j)}{q(x_j)} - y_j \right)^2$: the equations you get are nonlinear.  What you can do is minimize
$\sum_j (p(x_j) - y_j q(x_j))^2$, where to keep things nontrivial you require e.g. $q(0)= 1$.  If you write $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n p_i x^i$ and $q(x) =  \sum_{i=0}^m q_i x^i$ with $q_0 = 1$, the equations are

$$\eqalign{\sum_j (p(x_j) - y_j q(x_j)) x_j^i &= 0, \ i = 0\ldots n \cr
          \sum_j (p(x_j) - y_j q(x_j)) y_j x_j^i &= 0, \ i = 1 \ldots m\cr}$$

Thus for equation $i$ in the first group of equations, the coefficient of
$p_k$ is $\sum_j x_j^{k+i}$ and the coefficient of $q_k$ is $- \sum_j y_j x_j^{k+i}$.
For equation $i$ in the second group, the coefficients are 
$\sum_j y_j x_j^{k+i}$ and $-\sum_j y_j^2 x_j^{k+i}$.  Since $q_0 = 1$ is
constant, its coefficients are moved over to the right side.

EDIT:  For example, with $n = 3$ and $m=2$, the system is
$$ \pmatrix{ \sum_j 1 & \sum_j x_j & \sum_j x_j^2 & \sum_j x_j^3 & - \sum_j y_j x_j & - \sum_j y_j x_j^2\cr
 \sum_j x_j & \sum_j x_j^2 & \sum_j x_j^3 & \sum_j x_j^4 & - \sum_j y_j x_j^2 & - \sum_j y_j x_j^3\cr
 \sum_j x_j^2 & \sum_j x_j^3 & \sum_j x_j^4 & \sum_j x_j^5 & - \sum_j y_j x_j^3 & - \sum_j y_j x_j^4\cr
 \sum_j x_j^3 & \sum_j x_j^4 & \sum_j x_j^5 & \sum_j x_j^6 & - \sum_j y_j x_j^4 & - \sum_j y_j x_j^5\cr
\sum_j y_j x_j & \sum_j y_j x_j^2 & \sum_j y_j x_j^3 & \sum_j y_j x_j^4 & - \sum_j y_j^2 x_j^2 & - \sum_j y_j^2 x_j^3\cr
\sum_j y_j x_j^2 & \sum_j y_j x_j^3 & \sum_j y_j x_j^4 & \sum_j y_j x_j^5 & - \sum_j y_j^2 x_j^3 & - \sum_j y_j^2 x_j^4\cr} \pmatrix{p_0\cr p_1\cr p_2\cr p_3\cr q_1\cr q_2\cr} = \pmatrix{\sum_j y_j\cr
 \sum_j y_j x_j \cr \sum_j y_j x_j^2 \cr \sum_j y_j x_j^3\cr \sum_j y_j^2 x_j\cr \sum_j y_j^2 x_j^2\cr}$$

Comment: Ok, do you know how to set up the Matrix like in the link I gave above, in situation where you have more points than you need to find the coefficients and you want the rational function to adequately fit all the points.  That's the problem I'm having:  how do you set up the Matrix so that I can use Gaussian-Jordan Elimination to solve it.

Comment: @Robert Israel. May I point out that your very effective approach leads to good and consistent values for the guesses of the parameters which required to be fine tuned by nonlinear regression ?

Comment: That is perfect.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Your caveat is so diplomatically phrased that I missed its importance, until I went and painfully re-discovered it myself.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_and_rational_function_modeling#Advantages_2) puts it a bit more plainly:  "This type of fit [...] should only be used to obtain starting values for the nonlinear fit. The statistical properties of fits like this are not well understood."